# I want to display Image after browse in aspFileupload control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I'm trying to show image in `<img>` after browse in fileupload control. I've tried to to put the asp button to show, it worked, but after the image show the fileupload control `No Files Selected`. I want to show the image and name of selected file in fileupload control at the same time.

**My aspx code**

```
<asp:Image ID ="MyImageUrl" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:FileUpload ID ="ImgPath" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="myShow" Text="Show" runat="server" />
```

**My Code behind**

```
Protected Sub myShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myShow.Click
     p = Server.MapPath("Image/" + ImgPath.PostedFile.FileName)
     ImgPath.SaveAs(p)
     MyImageUrl.ImageUrl = "Image/" + ImgPath.PostedFile.FileName
End Sub
```

Comment: you can not do that , the way you try. You need to use fully javascript code to select and show the image before you upload it to server. Look for some tutorial...

Comment: thank you, I know what to do.